# How to i display ALL of my data from Firebase Realtime Database in to TextView

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

All I get is nullPointerException or one item from the database. I want to display all the English words and it's Arabic counterpart. Do I have to use a RecylerView or something?. I also tried to put the output from { MyWords words = postSnapshot.getValue(MyWords.class)} into an ArrayList but that didn't work is well. help!

```
 DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("My Words"); 
 TextView englishView, arabicView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.displaying);
    readData();
}


private void readData() {
    englishView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    arabicView = findViewById(R.id.arabicView1);

    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                MyWords words = postSnapshot.getValue(MyWords.class);

                englishView.setText(words.getEnglish());
                arabicView.setText(words.getArabic());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) 
        {
             Log.d("TAG" , databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

my MyWords Class

```
private String english;
private String arabic;

public MyWords(String english, String arabic) {
    this.english = english;
    this.arabic = arabic;
}

public MyWords() {
}


public String getEnglish() {
    return english;
}

public void setEnglish(String english) {
    this.english = english;
}

public String getArabic() {
    return arabic;
}

public void setArabic(String arabic) {
    this.arabic = arabic;
}
```

my Json on firebase

```
   {
  "My Words" : {
    "office" : {
      "arabic" : "مكتب",
      "english" : "office"
    },
    "pen" : {
      "arabic" : "الغلم",
      "english" : "pen"
    },
    "teacher" : {
      "arabic" : "مدرسة",
      "english" : "teacher"
    },
    "university" : {
      "arabic" : "الجميع",
      "english" : "university"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: From above code you can only set University data to TextView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made few changes to your code and made comment there about the mistakes. In the textbox variable you were overwriting the content every-time as the textVeiw.setContent() function was called inside the for loop.

```
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("My Words");
TextView englishView, arabicView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.displaying);
    readData();
}
private void readData() {
    englishView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    arabicView = findViewById(R.id.arabicView1);
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                MyWords words = postSnapshot.getValue(MyWords.class);

                //here you were overwritting the content of the textbox everytime.
                englishView.setText( englishView.getText()+" "+ words.getEnglish());
                arabicView.setText(arabicView.getText()+" " +words.getArabic());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d("TAG" , databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Either this or you can use arraylist to of MyWords type and store the entire json then you can put the arraylist in the textView.

Comment: can you explain difference between his and your code sir ?

Comment: Sure @Ashish if you'll notice the for loop you'll see that he is setting the content of textView every-time that is why he can see only one tuple in textView. i've you get and set together so that the instead of overwriting it takes the existing tuples and then append the new tuple.

Comment: Android Studio is suggesting that getEnglish(); and getArabic(); methods may produce nullPointerException? should I ignore it or can I do something about it? however, the suggestion did work. Thanks

Comment: you can use words.getEnglish.isEmpty(); as a conditional statement to avoid null values. @AhmedAbdullah

Comment: If the answer as satisfactory then approve the answer as it is not accepted by you till now.

Comment: @Prashant verma thank you it works, and I did try to approve but it says "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"